# Chrome unable to scroll when using TinyMCE

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, tinymce

After I have done "init" on my TinyMCE textboxes the window is unable to scroll when using chrome. It freezes and nothing can be done unless I resize the window.

Has anyone had this issue and if so, how did you solve it?

It works in all other browsers and my chrome version is 25.0.1364.172

Thanks!

-- EDIT --
This is the init for tinyMCE. The "editor_selector" and "tinymce" are classes.

```
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector: "tinymce_wide",
            encoding: "xml",
            theme: "advanced",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,|,link,unlink",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            width: "918"
        });

        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector: "tinymce",
            encoding: "xml",
            theme: "advanced",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,|,link,unlink",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
            width: "705"
        });
```

Comment: what javascript error do you get, what version of tinymce are you using, your configuration?

Comment: TinyMCE is 3.5.8 and I do not get any error. It just freezes as explained above.

Comment: there are some cases when initializing that do not output any errors. are you using more than one editor? please post your full tinymce configuration (init function). does it work with other browsers?

Comment: I've made an edit above. It works in all other browser, even IE7 and above

Comment: hmm, no idea here - i use chrome not very often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll bar of the DIV in which tinymce was placed will freeze if your URL has got a # at the end.

I faced this issue in chrome browser. all other browsers had no problem.

You can see the related [Tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=106909) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188421/tinymce-ckeditor-freezing-container-divs-scrolling-when-initializing) threads.

Comment: As it seems right now it can have been the issue, explains why I havn't been able to recreate the issue more than once.

Comment: And thanks for the links as well, learned that mayby I should use NicEditor  instead in the future :)