# CKEditor "overflow: scroll" on parent causes toolbar to freeze at initial position

Tags: ckeditor, overflow

When you add a CKEditor to a div inside a div with: "overflow: scroll" the toolbar won't move when scrolling the parent div...

```
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow: scroll;">
    <div contenteditable="true">This is the ckedito</div>     
</div>
```

An example can be found here: ​http://jsfiddle.net/W8Dt4/

Does anyone know a workaround around this problem?

I think the desired behaviour would be:

- Keep the toolbar at the top of the editor div when there's enough room.
- Move the toolbar to the bottom of the editor div when there's not enough room on top and there is enough room on the bottom.

Comment: any progress on this? did you find a soltution?

Comment: In the end I used the floatingspace plugin and used custom javscript to set the position of the element (fixed or absolute) depending on the scrollposition

Answer (score 5):

Using version 4.4.3, I was able to solve this problem by fire the window scroll event in a similar way that it is done in other areas in CKEditor. Attach a scroll event to the parent container that has **overflow:scroll;** set on it and trigger the window scroll within. The positioning is a little clunky but still works.

```
$("#parent-with-scroll").on('scroll', function (evt) {
    CKEDITOR.document.getWindow().fire('scroll');
});
```

Comment: This solved my issue better than the big code block below.
I use a scrollable div inside a different div

Answer (score 0):

Yup. CKEditor never considered such case and, most likely, editor will never deal with such edge case.

Still, what you need is a scroll listener for `editor.element.getParent()` in [those lines](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/cd966e4f79d19a0cad33d397ae66308dbd09afb4/plugins/floatingspace/plugin.js#L270-L287) of `floatingspace` plugin. Unfortunately, you have to wait for the [ticket #9816](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9816) to be resolved, because it changes the way of re-positioning the toolbar, and makes your case possible to fix. Once the fix is released (in 4.2.1), you got to basically change the lines to look like this:

```
var elementParent = editor.element.getParent();

editor.on( 'focus', function( evt ) {
    ...
    elementParent.on( 'scroll', uiBuffer.input );
} );

editor.on( 'blur', function() {
    ...
    elementParent.removeListener( 'scroll', uiBuffer.input );
} );

editor.on( 'destroy', function() {
    ...
    elementParent.removeListener( 'scroll', uiBuffer.input );
} );
```

If you want, you can give it a try with this [ticket branch](https://github.com/cksource/ckeditor-dev/tree/t/9816). Otherwise, you got to need to wait for the upcoming release to patch your code.

There's also one thing that you need to know: each floating toolbar is appended to `<body>`, so it will never belong to the same (overflowed) container enclosing your editor. Even though the toolbar will scroll along with the container, it will always float **above** it and there's not much you can do about it unless you also hack [this line](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/floatingspace/plugin.js#L254). Note that I haven't tested it.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried your solution but without success. The editor throw's the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'eventsBuffer' " I guess that has something to do with this commit? https://github.com/cksource/ckeditor-dev/commit/22159642684478098561043f475b3f5e9eec6ad9

Comment: Yep. This is something totally new.